# How to add event addListener click on marker after search place on Google Maps

Tags: javascript, jquery, google-maps, google-maps-api-3

please help, i really confused to add event click on marker after success search place on google maps. i have try in some project that add event click on marker and work but not use method search place that mean use hardcode marker position and for this case  i hope someone can help me this is my code.

```
function initMap() {
  var mapOptions = {
    center: new google.maps.LatLng(0.7893, 113.9213),
    zoom: 4,
    mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP
  };
  map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map'), mapOptions);
  var input = document.getElementById('search_location_input');
  var searchBox = new google.maps.places.SearchBox(input);
  map.controls[google.maps.ControlPosition.TOP_LEFT].push(input);
  // Bias the SearchBox results towards current map's viewport.
  map.addListener('bounds_changed', function() {
    searchBox.setBounds(map.getBounds());
  });
  // marker
  var markers = [];
  // Listen for the event fired when the user selects a prediction and retrieve
  // more details for that place.
  searchBox.addListener('places_changed', function() {
    var places = searchBox.getPlaces();
    if (places.length == 0) {
      return;
    }
    // Clear out the old markers.
    markers.forEach(function(marker) {
      marker.setMap(null);
    });
    markers = [];
    // For each place, get the icon, name and location.
    var bounds = new google.maps.LatLngBounds();
    places.forEach(function(place) {
      if (!place.geometry) {
        console.log("Returned place contains no geometry");
        return;
      }
      // Create a marker for each place.
      markers.push(new google.maps.Marker({
        map: map,
        title: place.name,
        position: place.geometry.location
      }));
      if (place.geometry.viewport) {
        bounds.union(place.geometry.viewport);
      } else {
        bounds.extend(place.geometry.location);
      }
    });
    map.fitBounds(bounds);
    for (var i = 0; i < markers.length; i++) {
      var data = markers[i];
      (function(marker, data) {
        google.maps.event.addListener(marker, "click", function(e) {
          console.log(data.title);
        });
      })(markers, data);
    }
  });
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I added `addListener` to the marker just after the marker is formed in loop `places.forEach(function(place) {...})`.

[Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/deep3015/skqvmk77/1/)

```
var map;


function initMap() {
  var mapOptions = {
    center: new google.maps.LatLng(0.7893, 113.9213),
    zoom: 4,
    mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP
  };
  map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map'), mapOptions);
  var input = document.getElementById('search_location_input');
  var searchBox = new google.maps.places.SearchBox(input);
  map.controls[google.maps.ControlPosition.TOP_LEFT].push(input);
  // Bias the SearchBox results towards current map's viewport.
  map.addListener('bounds_changed', function() {
    searchBox.setBounds(map.getBounds());
  });
  // marker
  var markers = [];
  // Listen for the event fired when the user selects a prediction and retrieve
  // more details for that place.
  searchBox.addListener('places_changed', function() {
    var places = searchBox.getPlaces();
    if (places.length == 0) {
      return;
    }
    // Clear out the old markers.
    markers.forEach(function(marker) {
      marker.setMap(null);
    });
    markers = [];
    // For each place, get the icon, name and location.
    var bounds = new google.maps.LatLngBounds();
    places.forEach(function(place) {
      if (!place.geometry) {
        console.log("Returned place contains no geometry");
        return;
      }
      // Create a marker for each place.
      var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
        map: map,
        title: place.name,
        position: place.geometry.location
      })
      markers.push(marker);
      /*adding event addlistner*/
      google.maps.event.addListener(marker, "click", function(e) {
        console.log(place.name);
      });
      if (place.geometry.viewport) {
        bounds.union(place.geometry.viewport);
      } else {
        bounds.extend(place.geometry.location);
      }
    });
    map.fitBounds(bounds);

  });
}
```

Comment: thanks for you answer i have try to solve my problem and get solution only add index for marker when looping

Answer (score 1):

```
map.fitBounds(bounds); 
    for (var i = 0; i < markers.length; i++) {
      markers[i].index = i; //add index property
      var data = markers[i];
    //  var latitude = data.position.lat();
    //  var longitude = data.position.lng(); 
      google.maps.event.addListener(markers[i],'click', function(e) {
          var title = markers[this.index].title;
          var latitude = markers[this.index].position.lat();
          var longitude = markers[this.index].position.lng();
          console.log(this.index);
          console.log(title);
          console.log(latitude);
          console.log(longitude);
      });
    }
```

Comment: Good you have added another way